# How is the equivalent of 'module.exports = {};' in es6 for postcss.config.js?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, postcss

I am using `postcss` loader in webapck2.  The loader expects a config file `postcss.config.js`. I do not need any option. This issue comment (https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues/604#issuecomment-271974780) suggests I can simply put this in  `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {};
```

However when I run webpack (`webpack -p --config webpack.config.js`), I got these error message

```
ERROR in ./~/postcss-loader!./~/css-loader?{"modules":true}!./~/less-loader!./app/scripts/components/forms/form.less
Module build failed: Unknown word (1:1)

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")();
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 |
```

I think it is because my babel loader also applies to all files with `.js` extension and `module.exports = {};` is probably not translated well by `babel`.

What is the right syntax in es6 to define empty module export?

If I just commented out the line, I got the same error.

If I left the file blank, then postcss complaints about missing config file:

```
ERROR in ./~/postcss-loader!./~/css-loader?{"modules":true}!./~/less-loader!./app/scripts/components/forms/form.less
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /Users/antkong/dev/project/app/scripts/components/forms
    at Error (native)
    at /Users/antkong/dev/project/node_modules/postcss-load-config/index.js:51:26
```

I am using postcss-loader 1.1.0 and webpack 2.3.3

Comment: `export default {};` ?

Comment: I got this `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

Comment: Well, that's what you asked in your "How is the equivalent of 'module.exports = {};' in es6?" :shrug: It's not obvious what you're doing there.

Comment: Well, the question text provides context

Comment: I am running `postcss-loader` without `postcss.config.js` and I did not need any dirty hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the config, and you wouldn't be able to use ES modules unless you transpiled the config first.

You apply the `postcss-loader` after the `css-loader`, which generated JavaScript and that is not valid CSS, but that's what `postcss-loader` expects. The `postcss-loader` should be between the `css-loader` and the `less-loader`.

Your `.less` rule would look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true
      }
    },
    'postcss-loader',
    'less-loader'
  ]
}
```

Or if you're using `extract-text-webpack-plugin`:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true
        }
      },
      'postcss-loader',
      'less-loader'
    ]
  })
}
```